# Can not delete Test Plan / Suite in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops, test-plan

Can anyone help me to delete items below?
I already set the permissions, may I missing something?

[image]

[image]

**Error message**
Failed to delete work item: 8423. Error Details: You don't have sufficient permissions to delete this work item. You must have work item and test artifacts delete permissions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your access level? From the documentation: *To have full access to the Test feature set, your access level must be set to Basic + Test Plans. Users with Basic access and with permissions to permanently delete work items and manage test artifacts can only delete orphaned test cases.*

Comment: You got the point.
I have only Visual Studio Professional subscription. It does not include Test Plans.

Thank you! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Daniel Mann, Test Plans subscription is required to manage Test Plans.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for your kindly sharing, you could *mark your reply as an answer*, which will also help others in the community.

Comment: That is a correct answer!